# A practical way to implement a reliable uninterruptible countdown timer without using a database

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement a countdown timer that can run independently of phone shutdowns and reboots i.e once the user clicks a button, my app initiates a countdown timer. Specifically, I'm looking for a way to tell how much time has passed since the user clicked the button...reliably.

Given the above requirements, I use `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()` and `System.currentTimeMillis()` to keep track of the below.

1. The time the button was clicked `long clickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()`.
2. The time phone stayed on before shutdown `long timeB4SD = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - clickTime`
3. The time at shutdown `long clockATSD = System.currentTimeMillis()`
4. The time immediately at reboot `long clockATRB = System.currentTimeMillis()`
5. The time spent off `long timeSpentOff = clockATRB - clockATSD`
6. The time spent away from the app since reboot `long timeAfterRB = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - 0`

I can then get the time spent away from the screen by sum `long timeAway4rmScreen = timeB4SD + timeSpentOff + timeAfterRB`...and use that to update my countdown timer.

To run this successfully, I need access to `Intent.ACTION_SHUTDOWN`. As of `Build.VERSION_CODES.P`, the issue comes in when the user does not run the app between reboot and shutdown, hence I cannot run `registerReceiver(new ShutDownReboot(), new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SHUTDOWN))` and any time between reboot and shutdown is lost if the user does not run my app during that time.

So I'm wondering if there is a way around this, or if there is a better way to implement a countdown timer?

Answer (score 0):

Look into `SharedPreferences` when the user starts a timer you save the `System.currentTimeMillis()` in `SharedPreferences` as the app is running your UI runs independently. After reboot or app close on app start up you use `System.currentTimeMillis()` stored in `SharedPreferences` to restore the current time elapsed to the count down timer. Unless I'm missing something in your requirements you only need to record the start time and you can rebuild the timer from there at anytime.

Comment: A user can change `System.currentTimeMillis()` by changing the time. `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()` is more reliable for this particular purpose.

Comment: Well a user that intends to manipulate the App won't care to much about `SystemClock` or anything its got to say either. Pit fall of not using a external database.